# Authorization Error when Connecting to Youtube Analytics API with Python

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I have been trying to connect during several days to the YouTube Analytics API. I see that the solution in other posts is related about selecting 'Others' in the Application Type list. Apparently, this option is not available anymore.

I have created two different OAuth 2.0 clients: Web Application and Desktop. For the first one, it is displaying the following error:

- Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch: The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type.

Then, it is when I try to create a native application (Desktop App in this case), it is sending a new error message:

- Error 400: invalid_request. You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure. You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.

I have read the Google's OAuth 2.0 policy but I am not able to understand why it doesn't comply. It's not quite specific.

Anyone that has had the same issue? This is the sample code that I have been using:

```
import googleapiclient.errors
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    #os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtubeAnalytics"
    api_version = "v2"
    client_secrets_file = "cliente_analytics.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube_analytics = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube_analytics.reports().query(
        dimensions="day",
        endDate="2021-04-01",
        ids="channel==MINE",
        maxResults=5,
        metrics="likes",
        startDate="2021-03-01"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using is designed for an installed application hence the

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    client_secrets_file, scopes)
```

fixing `invalid_request. You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.`

Can be a bit tricking.

- Make sure the app is running https.
- Check that its still set to testing in google cloud console
- Make sure the name of your project in google developer console doesn't contain the world Google or any google products.  For example naming your project BEST YOUTUBE app is not going to pass.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It would work if I set up the app to testing or I need to create a new one? Thanks a lot again!!

Comment: Your app needs to go though verification before its going to work setting it to production.